# Tag name: homographic-kanji → homographs?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag name [homographic-kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homographic-kanji) sounds strange to me, because when two kanji letters are homographic, what it really means is that the two kanji letters are *the same*, not *homographic*.  As I understand it, the tag is about homographic *words*.

I propose to change the tag name to [homographs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homographs).  Another candidate is [homographic-words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homographic-words), but I think that the simple [homographs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homographs) is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [homographic-kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homographic-kanji) because I saw there was a [homophonic-kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homophonic-kanji) tag, but I think you're right.

For me it can be turned to [homographs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homographs).

Comment: I see.  If you are fine with [homographs], please feel free to change it or wait for a bit to see if there are other opinions/options.

Comment: I thought about changing it, but let's wait to see some other opinions, although I think your proposal works fine. :)

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I tried to change it, but accidentally created a similar one. Can you fix it? I don't have the privileges.

Comment: I can fix the tag, but I do not know what you mean by “accidentally created a similar one.”  Because you can always edit your own questions, I do not know which privileges you are talking about.

Comment: I changed my tag in my question and now there are two tags: a [homographs] and a [homographic-kanji] one. I can't delete the one I created and rename the existing one... :)

Comment: I do not see the change: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/homographs-how-to-deal-with-them.  It does not have any history of edits.  Which question are you talking about?

Comment: If you are talking about [the tags page](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags) or autocompletion, then do not bother, because unused tags will be removed from the list automatically in one or two days.

Comment: Yes I knew that, but if someone uses it, it won't die... Well, we'll wait and see. :)

Comment: (1) I created a chat room for this by mistake.  Please disregard it.  (2) In the worst case, we can ask moderators to merge an old tag to a new tag.  Let’s not worry about the rare case.

Comment: I have merged and created [synonym](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). Let me know if I got the discussion wrong way.

Comment: @YOU Hello! So... The decision was to completely delete (homographic-kanji) and only keep (homographs) since I don't think someone will actually type the other one, it was just my mistake. If someone starts typing "hom..." they'll get the (homographs) one and it will work, I suppose. Also, I made the tag wiki for the one we wanted to delete, so you can copy all of that to the new tag. Thanks a lot! :D